# Mapbox Android Draw polygon by adding markers

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am new to Mapbox, I want to add polygon endpoints and generate a polygon. once polygon is generated I want to get this endpoint for further processing, can I do this using mapBox? I have seen an example of generating polygon by adding predefined points, I want to do this by user interaction.

Comment: Mapbox doesn't have a direct port of https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw for the gl-native ecosystem. That said. you should be able to get this to work with the annotation plugin https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-annotation

Comment: @Tobrun, can you show me some example code? I have looked into their documentation but it just shows the predefined points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapbox Provides land Selection for this type of scenario. please look more info here.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/satellite-land-select/